how do I activate copilot while running pycharm on remote server through X11?
I want to activate copilot on pycharm when running pycharm on remote server with X11 forwarding, I go to options and see this link:

The second dropdown doesn't work, its empty even if I click "Manage GitHub accounts", there is an account there. So I click "GitHub Copilot account settings", it opens unresponsive FireFox window, which is dead, i can't even close it:

I tried opening the link in another browser, but there is nothing interesting on the page, it doesn't allow me to connect copilot to pycharm. I tried to change default browser to chromium-browser, but it fails to work on my terminal Mobaxterm itself, it doesn't start. So, how can I activate copilot?
